# Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, package, nuget

I use Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
NuGet Package Manager   3.4.4

When trying to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package in a .NET 4.6.1 console Application project, I get the following error:

```
   install-package : Could not install package 'runtime.native.System 4.0.0-rc2-24027'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc -pre
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can not install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` in a console Application. In a console application from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` you can install only `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ActiveDirectory`.
To prove this try this way:

1. Right click in the references
2. Chose `Manage Nuget Packages...`
3. From 3 tabs (Browse, Installed, Updates) choose `Browse` tab.
4. Write in the search box `Microsoft.AspNetCore.`
   The reason you can not install that your application is simply a `console app` not `MVC` structure.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone, like me, who is looking for a way to do this on a Core 3.1 or .NET 5+ console project, the correct way to do this is no longer to install the package but to add the framework, "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App", to the project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

See [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) for more info.